# Running Spark-Shell on Windows

Tags: windows, scala, apache-spark

I have downloaded spark, sbt, scala, and git onto my Windows computer. When I try and run spark-shell in my command prompt, I get "Failed to find Spark assembly JAR. You need to build Spark with sbt\sbt assembly before running this program."

I tried to follow this guide: https://x86x64.wordpress.com/2015/04/29/installing-spark-on-windows/ ,but I don't have a build subfolder so I am not sure if that is the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's an old guide for spark 1.3.

Please use this guide to set up spark on Windows.

http://www.ics.uci.edu/~shantas/Install_Spark_on_Windows10.pdf

This guide uses Maven and you are going to use sbt but nevertheless you will be able to execute spark-shell with this guide.